# Plotly choropleth map hanging with no error in Python

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I am generating a Choropleth map using plotly but my script is hanging with no error when I call the below code.  I cannot figure out the root cause of this issue - it is confusing as the exact same code works fine for me in a different script.  I have loaded all of the dependencies the exact same way in the other script too.

I have reinstalled plotly to no avail and have turned off all other map creations in the script to see if the order they are run in makes any difference. No luck with any of these.

Any advice would be very much appreciated - Thanks!

Problem lines:

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(salesStats, geojson=json.loads(salesStats.to_json()), 
    locations=salesStats.index, 
    color='Res_house_medianPrice_qtr10YrCagrPCI',
    color_continuous_scale=cc_scale, 
    range_color=(0, 100),
    mapbox_style="carto-positron", 
    zoom=10, center = {"lat": centroid[1], "lon": centroid[0]}, 
    opacity=0.8
    
)
```

Dataframe:

```
{'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}, 'SA2_CODE21': {0: '101021007', 1: '101021008', 2: '101021009', 3: '101021010', 4: '101021012', 5: '101021610', 6: '101021611', 7: '101031013', 8: '101031014', 9: '101031015'}, 'geometry': {0: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBE490>, 1: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBEE80>, 2: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBEA60>, 3: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBED00>, 4: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBE340>, 5: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBE6D0>, 6: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBE4F0>, 7: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBE820>, 8: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBE5B0>, 9: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBEDF0>}, 'areaCode': {0: '101021007', 1: '101021008', 2: '101021009', 3: '101021010', 4: '101021012', 5: '101021610', 6: '101021611', 7: '101031013', 8: '101031014', 9: '101031015'}, 'Res_house_medianPrice_qtr10YrCagrPCI': {0: 19.0, 1: 19.0, 2: 8.0, 3: 99.0, 4: 13.0, 5: nan, 6: 12.0, 7: 5.0, 8: 92.0, 9: 95.0}}
```

Custom colour scale (cc_scale):

```
[(0, '#1e040d'), (0.03028125, '#1e040d'), (0.03028125, '#20040e'), (0.0409375, '#20040e'), (0.0409375, '#22050f'), (0.050625, '#22050f'), (0.050625, '#240510'), (0.0603125, '#240510'), (0.0603125, '#260611'), (0.07, '#260611'), (0.07, '#280612'), (0.07968750000000001, '#280612'), (0.07968750000000001, '#2a0613'), (0.089375, '#2a0613'), (0.089375, '#2c0714'), (0.09906250000000001, '#2c0714'), (0.09906250000000001, '#2e0715'), (0.10875000000000001, '#2e0715'), (0.10875000000000001, '#300716'), (0.11843750000000001, '#300716'), (0.11843750000000001, '#320816'), (0.12812500000000002, '#320816'), (0.12812500000000002, '#340817'), (0.1378125, '#340817'), (0.1378125, '#360918'), (0.1475, '#360918'), (0.1475, '#370919'), (0.1571875, '#370919'), (0.1571875, '#39091a'), (0.16687500000000002, '#39091a'), (0.16687500000000002, '#3b0a1b'), (0.17656250000000004, '#3b0a1b'), (0.17656250000000004, '#3d0a1c'), (0.18625000000000003, '#3d0a1c'), (0.18625000000000003, '#3f0a1d'), (0.19593750000000001, '#3f0a1d'), (0.19593750000000001, '#410b1e'), (0.20562500000000003, '#410b1e'), (0.20562500000000003, '#430b1f'), (0.21531250000000002, '#430b1f'), (0.21531250000000002, '#450c20'), (0.225, '#450c20'), (0.225, '#470c21'), (0.23468750000000002, '#470c21'), (0.23468750000000002, '#490c22'), (0.244375, '#490c22'), (0.244375, '#4b0d23'), (0.2540625, '#4b0d23'), (0.2540625, '#4d0d24'), (0.26375, '#4d0d24'), (0.26375, '#4f0e25'), (0.2734375, '#4f0e25'), (0.2734375, '#510e26'), (0.283125, '#510e26'), (0.283125, '#530e27'), (0.29281250000000003, '#530e27'), (0.29281250000000003, '#550f28'), (0.30250000000000005, '#550f28'), (0.30250000000000005, '#570f29'), (0.3121875, '#570f29'), (0.3121875, '#590f29'), (0.321875, '#590f29'), (0.321875, '#5b102a'), (0.33156250000000004, '#5b102a'), (0.33156250000000004, '#5d102b'), (0.34125000000000005, '#5d102b'), (0.34125000000000005, '#5f112c'), (0.35093749999999996, '#5f112c'), (0.35093749999999996, '#61112d'), (0.36062500000000003, '#61112d'), (0.36062500000000003, '#63112e'), (0.37031250000000004, '#63112e'), (0.37031250000000004, '#65122f'), (0.38000000000000006, '#65122f'), (0.38000000000000006, '#671230'), (0.3896875, '#671230'), (0.3896875, '#681231'), (0.39937500000000004, '#681231'), (0.39937500000000004, '#6a1332'), (0.40906250000000005, '#6a1332'), (0.40906250000000005, '#6c1333'), (0.41875, '#6c1333'), (0.41875, '#6e1434'), (0.4284375, '#6e1434'), (0.4284375, '#701435'), (0.43812500000000004, '#701435'), (0.43812500000000004, '#721436'), (0.4478125, '#721436'), (0.4478125, '#741537'), (0.4575, '#741537'), (0.4575, '#761538'), (0.46718750000000003, '#761538'), (0.46718750000000003, '#781539'), (0.476875, '#781539'), (0.476875, '#7a163a'), (0.4865625, '#7a163a'), (0.4865625, '#7c163b'), (0.49625, '#7c163b'), (0.49625, '#7e173c'), (0.5059375, '#7e173c'), (0.5059375, '#80173c'), (0.515625, '#80173c'), (0.515625, '#82173d'), (0.5253125, '#82173d'), (0.5253125, '#84183e'), (0.535, '#84183e'), (0.535, '#86183f'), (0.5446875, '#86183f'), (0.5446875, '#881940'), (0.5543750000000001, '#881940'), (0.5543750000000001, '#8a1941'), (0.5640625, '#8a1941'), (0.5640625, '#8c1942'), (0.5737500000000001, '#8c1942'), (0.5737500000000001, '#8e1a43'), (0.5834375, '#8e1a43'), (0.5834375, '#901a44'), (0.593125, '#901a44'), (0.593125, '#921a45'), (0.6028125000000001, '#921a45'), (0.6028125000000001, '#941b46'), (0.6125, '#941b46'), (0.6125, '#961b47'), (0.6221875, '#961b47'), (0.6221875, '#981c48'), (0.6318750000000001, '#981c48'), (0.6318750000000001, '#991c49'), (0.6415625, '#991c49'), (0.6415625, '#9b1c4a'), (0.65125, '#9b1c4a'), (0.65125, '#9d1d4b'), (0.6609375000000001, '#9d1d4b'), (0.6609375000000001, '#9f1d4c'), (0.6706249999999999, '#9f1d4c'), (0.6706249999999999, '#a11d4d'), (0.6803125, '#a11d4d'), (0.6803125, '#a31e4e'), (0.6900000000000001, '#a31e4e'), (0.6900000000000001, '#a51e4f'), (0.6996875, '#a51e4f'), (0.6996875, '#a71f50'), (0.7093750000000001, '#a71f50'), (0.7093750000000001, '#a91f50'), (0.7190625, '#a91f50'), (0.7190625, '#ab1f51'), (0.7287500000000001, '#ab1f51'), (0.7287500000000001, '#ad2052'), (0.7384375, '#ad2052'), (0.7384375, '#af2053'), (0.748125, '#af2053'), (0.748125, '#b12054'), (0.7578125, '#b12054'), (0.7578125, '#b32155'), (0.7675000000000001, '#b32155'), (0.7675000000000001, '#b52156'), (0.7771875, '#b52156'), (0.7771875, '#b72257'), (0.7868750000000001, '#b72257'), (0.7868750000000001, '#b92258'), (0.7965625, '#b92258'), (0.7965625, '#bb2259'), (0.80625, '#bb2259'), (0.80625, '#bd235a'), (0.8159375, '#bd235a'), (0.8159375, '#bf235b'), (0.825625, '#bf235b'), (0.825625, '#c1245c'), (0.8353125, '#c1245c'), (0.8353125, '#c3245d'), (0.8450000000000001, '#c3245d'), (0.8450000000000001, '#c5245e'), (0.8546874999999999, '#c5245e'), (0.8546874999999999, '#c7255f'), (0.864375, '#c7255f'), (0.864375, '#c92560'), (0.8740625000000001, '#c92560'), (0.8740625000000001, '#ca2561'), (0.88375, '#ca2561'), (0.88375, '#cc2662'), (0.8934375000000001, '#cc2662'), (0.8934375000000001, '#ce2662'), (0.9031250000000001, '#ce2662'), (0.9031250000000001, '#d02763'), (0.9128125000000001, '#d02763'), (0.9128125000000001, '#d22764'), (0.9225, '#d22764'), (0.9225, '#d42765'), (0.9321875000000001, '#d42765'), (0.9321875000000001, '#d62866'), (0.941875, '#d62866'), (0.941875, '#d82867'), (0.9515625000000001, '#d82867'), (0.9515625000000001, '#da2868'), (0.96125, '#da2868'), (0.96125, '#dc2969'), (0.9709375000000001, '#dc2969'), (0.9709375000000001, '#de296a'), (0.980625, '#de296a'), (0.980625, '#e02a6b'), (0.9903125, '#e02a6b'), (0.9903125, '#e22a6c'), (1, '#e02a6b')]
```

Comment: can you include a sample of `salesStats` so we can reproduce your figure? you can copy and paste the output from `salesStats.head(10).to_dict()` directly into your question, thanks

Comment: Thank you very much Derek, done.  Is it possible for you to convert '<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000017833FBE5B0>' and such, or do you need me to share as geojson instead (I'd imagine that might breach a stacj voerflow character limit)?

Comment: Also, more info which may be useful/important - this issue is only affecting choloropleth maps, not scatter.  Additionally, the difference between this script and the other test script which worked is that this one involves threading.  The problem code is also positioned after code that runs excel macros, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the data in the updated question. You need a data frame that is user data, a geojson or geopandas file, and a successful output figure. Do you have a similar example in your reference? See [here](https://plotly.com/python/maps/).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Derek.  I've realised it's easier to perform this section of the script by calling an external script as the original script has a lot going on which will make diagnosing the issue hard without sending you a ton of stuff.   Thanks again! Ronan

Comment: @ronan i'm not sure if i did much to help besides suggest how to make your question reproducible – but i'll take the compliment and i'm happy you figured out a solution that works! if you have the time, you should consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.) – this will help future users who have the same question as you.  cheers